# Wordpress. Шаблон cactus. Размер нижнего подчеркивания :after

Tags: css

На скриншоте видно, что полоска `:before`  отображается от начала до конца, но полоска `:after` сдвинута направо (хоть и параметры выставлены одинаково). Игрался с разными параметрами, но так и не получилось полоску `:after`  выставить с самого начала.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ни к WordPress, ни к теме cactus, вопрос не имеет отношения. Чистая проблема вёрстки.

Псевдоэлемент `after` ведёт себя как положено, потому что получает 100% ширины родителя `.cactus-navigation`. А вот `before` у вас на всю ширину, потому что имеет

```
padding: 0 1000px;
margin-left: -1000px;
```

заданный для

```
.cactus-style-solid-bg:before, .cactus-style-bottom-line-full:before, .cactus-style-top-line-full:before
```

в `/wp-content/themes/cactus/style.css?ver=4.9.4` строка 3386.

Задайте такое же извращение блоку after, и всё получится.

Но вёрстка в целом жесть.